# Multisig wallet for Cardano?

Tags: wallet, multisig

Does Cardano support multisig wallets? If not, are there any ongoing projects to have them implemented, any standards defined or at least drafts proposed?

Answer (score 9):

The node does support multi-signatures (for instance you can do a multi-signature when minting NFTs). However, the wallets do not yet support this. But its coming eventually!

Comment: Are there any docs on those multi-signatures?

Comment: @MarekMahut-StakeNuts The links seems to be broken (404)

Answer (score 3):

[***Github Link for the comprehensive guide***](https://github.com/danivideda/multisig-wallet-with-staking-capability)

You can create your own Multisig Wallet using `cardano-cli` locally. However, this is for a technical people and with basic knowledge on how Cardano UTXO works and the concept of private/public key to sign transaction etc. The development of creating a user-friendly multi-sig wallet is still ongoing [Round Table](https://roundtable.theadao.io/)

There's a guide on how to create Cardano's Multi-sig Wallet + ability to stake the wallet.

Here's the general overview:

1. Generate public key pair of `payment.vkey` and `stake.vkey` (verification key) for your wallet and the participant's wallet
2. Create the script policy (using Native Script) and provide this information *basically telling who are the people that need to sign / approve transactions for this wallet
3. Create the address (called Script Address)
4. Everytime you want to do transaction with this wallet, participants need to sign the `.raw` transaction file using their private `payment.skey` or `stake.skey` file locally.

This is at the core level / behind the scene on how to create and use multi-sig wallet on Cardano.

Answer (score 2):

[CIP 1854](https://cips.cardano.org/cips/cip1854/) (Cardano Improvement Proposals) allows us to use Multi-signatures HD Wallets, but there's no implementation at the moment. However, in ***Goguen era***, which begins on 12th September 2021, Cardano with the help of ***Alonzo*** gives developers the tools to create Smart Contracts with Multisig.

Here's a quotation from [IOHK post](https://iohk.io/en/blog/posts/2021/04/08/smart-contracts-%E2%80%93-here-we-come/#):

> Applying a rigorous approach based on formal methods and verification, Alonzo extends the basic multi-signature scripting language (multisig) used in Cardano Shelley. Multisig will be upgraded to the Plutus Core language for more powerful and secure scripting options.

Answer (score 2):

I just launched https://broclan.io

Anyone looking for a multisig wallet on Cardano can give it a try :)

Comment: Leo, is broclan still up and running. As far as I can tell, it doesn't seem ready for mainnet yet?

Comment: @JacquesBosch its up an on Mainnet. If you need any help please reach out to me on twitter or Discord (links on the broclan website).

Answer (score 0):

Below are 2 more options I have found.

The Summon Platform
https://medium.com/@SummonPlatform/multi-signature-treasuries-ba855e748878

> Multi-signature Native scripts are one of the most secure ways of
> managing funds on the Cardano blockchain. Current use cases range from
> personal backups, trusts, or “fail-safes,” to subDAOs, guilds, working
> groups, investment clubs, hedge funds, p2p swaps, and even
> multi-player betting or gambling games. And that’s only scratching the
> surface. In the future, we expect to see many new and exciting use
> cases that benefit from this simple yet secure scripting language.
>
> ... The Summon multi-signature treasury system focuses heavily on user
> friendliness and easy treasury management. The interface allows you to
> assign signers/key holders by simply inputting their Cardano receiving
> address or by resolving their $ADAHandle directly in the UI.
>
> Create A Multi-Sig Treasury The Summon multi-signature treasury system
> requires no coding experience and is compatible with all popular
> Cardano lite wallets. Creating a new treasury is simple: ...

LedgerFlow by Iagon

https://docs.iagon.com/docs/whitepaper/products/ledgerflow/

Here is what they say:

> Ledgerflow is an innovative project that operates within the Cardano
> blockchain ecosystem. It offers two essential features: Multisender
> and Multisignature (Multisig) capabilities. Let's delve into each of
> these functionalities:
>
> Multisig is a powerful security feature that enhances the safety of
> cryptocurrency wallets and transactions. In a Multisig setup, multiple
> parties (often referred to as signatories) collaboratively manage a
> wallet. Transactions require approval from a predefined number of
> these signatories. For instance, a company treasury might use a
> Multisig wallet where three out of five board members must sign off on
> any outgoing transaction. This prevents unauthorized access and
> provides redundancy.